# foreach on IEnumerable or IList

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ with Entity framework to joining three tables and I am returning `IList` interface.

I want to apply `foreach` loop on this returned value so I can populate values in my model.

This is how I am joining:

```
public IList GetData(long Id)
{
    //var q = dataContext.tblUsers.AsEnumerable().Join(dataContext.tblUsersProfiles.AsEnumerable(),)
    var query = from u in dataContext.tblUsers
    join p in dataContext.tblUsersProfiles on u.ProfileId equals p.Id
    join c in dataContext.tblComments on u.Id equals c.Commentedby

    where c.Id == Id
    select new { u.Firstname, u.Lastname, p.ProfilePicPath, c.Comment, c.CommentDate };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I want to populate these values in my List of Model. I have tried this:

```
var lst = repository.GetDate(Id);
foreach (var item in lst)
{

}
```

But I am unable to access item `Firstname`/`Lastname` etc.

I also tried using object `item` and `object[] item` but they both are not working too.

How can I apply a `for`each`on`IList`?

It will work fine If I'm be able to return `DataTable` instead of `IList` in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous type. Just define a class for the result of your query, then the return type of your function should be like this:

```
public IList<YourClassName> GetData(long Id)
{

}
```

Finally set class values:

```
select new YourClassName 
{
    Firstname = u.Firstname,
    Lastname = u.Lastname, 
    ProfilePicPath = p.ProfilePicPath,
    Comment = c.Comment,
    CommentDate = c.CommentDate
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You're returning an `anonymous` list of `objects` in the method. You can access the properties by using reflection but this is abit slow at runtime. Easiest to get type information is by defining a class and use that in the `select` statement.

```
public class Person
{
   public string Firstname { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   /* ... */
}

public IList<Person> GetData(long Id)
{   
    var query = from u in dataContext.tblUsers
                join p in dataContext.tblUsersProfiles on u.ProfileId equals p.Id
                join c in dataContext.tblComments on u.Id equals c.Commentedby
                where c.Id == Id
                select new Person { u.Firstname, u.Lastname /* ... */ };
        return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous type:

```
select new { u.Firstname, u.Lastname, p.ProfilePicPath, c.Comment, c.CommentDate };
```

If you want to pass this data to other methods etc. you need to create a real class.

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicPath { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
}
```

and use it:

```
public IList<DataClass> GetData(long Id)
{
    var query = from u in dataContext.tblUsers
                join p in dataContext.tblUsersProfiles on u.ProfileId equals p.Id
                join c in dataContext.tblComments on u.Id equals c.Commentedby
                where c.Id == Id
    select new DataClass
    {
        Firstname = u.Firstname,
        Lastname = u.Lastname,
        ProfilePicPath = p.ProfilePicPath,
        Comment = c.Comment,
        CommentDate = c.CommentDate
    };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return not just IList interface but parametrised interface with your type. Now you returtint anounymouse object.

So what i want to suggest. Create this class:

```
public class MyCustomContainer
{
   public string Firstname { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public string ProfilePicPath { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; } 
   public string CommentDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the change your method like this:

```
  public IList<MyCustomContainer> GetData(long Id)
        {
            //var q = dataContext.tblUsers.AsEnumerable().Join(dataContext.tblUsersProfiles.AsEnumerable(),)
            var query = from u in dataContext.tblUsers
                        join p in dataContext.tblUsersProfiles on u.ProfileId equals p.Id
                        join c in dataContext.tblComments on u.Id equals c.Commentedby
                        where c.Id == Id
                        select new MyCustomContainer 
                         { 
                             Firstname  = u.Firstname, 
                             Lastname = u.Lastname, 
                             ProfilePicPath = p.ProfilePicPath, 
                             Comment = c.Comment, 
                             CommentDate = c.CommentDate 
                          };
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Now you returning not anonymouse object within List so you can get all properties you need

Answer (score 0):

You're using an anonymous type so you can't cast it to anything when looping through your list. You could try using `dynamic` instead of `var` which means you can call any property on it as long as it exists at runtime:

```
foreach (dynamic item in lst)
{
    string firstName = item.FirstName;
}
```

or explicitly defining a class for the result item like the other answers are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You must change **GetData** return type. Please try this:

```
public List<tblUsers> GetData(long Id)
        {
            //var q = dataContext.tblUsers.AsEnumerable().Join(dataContext.tblUsersProfiles.AsEnumerable(),)
            var query = from u in dataContext.tblUsers
                        join p in dataContext.tblUsersProfiles on u.ProfileId equals p.Id
                        join c in dataContext.tblComments on u.Id equals c.Commentedby
                        where c.Id == Id
                        select new tblUsers { u.Firstname, u.Lastname, p.ProfilePicPath, c.Comment, c.CommentDate };
            return query.ToList();
        }
```